# Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services recommends including a SharePoint web part Manager on all master page?

Tags: 2007, web-part

I create a master page using SharePoint Designer 2007 and when I click save as a 'sample.master' file, I encounter the following message:

`Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services recommends including a SharePoint Web Part Manager on all master page. Do you want to add a SharePoint Web Part Manager to the current page?`

So, what does it really mean? Will it affect all my master pages in my site?

Also, if I select `No` for the above question, I will be greeted with another message as follows:

`Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services requires including a SharePoint Robots Meta Tag control on master pages to secure search indexing on Web sites that use fine grained permissions. Do you want to add a SharePoint Robots Meta Tag to the current page?`

So, what does all these messages mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Message1**: It is telling you that Web Part Manager code should be added at top of master page so that users can add/remove webpart on page. Webpart manager is responsible for managing the webparts and it should be on top of masterpage. There is no harm in having that code and also it don't have any displayable component on page so you won't notice anything.

**Message2**: These are meta tags to be added by SharePoint for searching to work properly. You should allow it be added and this also not going to affect you design.

In short you should allow both of things on you masterpage and it will not affect your design at all.